# Get connection speed of a program with netstat

Tags: ubuntu, wget, netstat

I use `netstat -natpe` to view the connections and program names. While wget is fetching data, the RX column is zero

```
naderan@student-virtual-machine:~$ netstat -natpe
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode      PID/Program name  
tcp        0      0 5.27.56.123:35358       78.35.24.46:443         ESTABLISHED 1002       682290     7143/wget
```

How can I get the speed of that connection?

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add an appropriate operating system tag.

Comment: `Recv-Q` will be 0 unless the network is sending data faster than your application (`wget`) can read data off of the network. Similarly, `Send-Q` will be 0 unless your application is sending data faster than the network can handle.

Answer (score 1):

install and run:

```
apt-get install bwm-ng

bwm-ng
```

which monitors the bw

Comment: That only shows the net speed. No user name, no process name, no ip, ...

Comment: Ah OK, but this, as good as i know does exists:program <-this you want-> net interface  
But for details: Traffic analysis works with "wireshark"

Comment: You must filter all other connections (if they do something) otherwise you need to setup new network interfaces, each for your whiches to track them and then bwm-ng works again

Comment: give this a try: https://github.com/raboof/nethogs